# Render multiple vulkan passes in the same attachment

Tags: vulkan

I wonder whether it is possible to render multiple passes into the same color and depth attachment in Vulkan? I need to do a headless rendering of a huge model that does not fit into the the GPU memory (I'm using Swiftshader that has only 1GB of memory). I'd like to do the following sequence of actions:

1. Initialize an empty color attachment and depth buffer
2. Setup the shader and graphics pipeline
3. Loop over chunks of vertices from my huge model
4. Upload the chunk of vertices from the CPU to the GPU
5. Render into the color and depth buffers (on "top" of the previous values in the color and depth attachments)
6. Repeat next chunk

I'm currently stuck on `vkCmdBeginRenderPass()` which takes a "clear value". But what if I don't want to clear the buffer. Can I just do `clearValues = 0`? What else is needed to get the scenario above to work?

Answer (score 2):

Whether a render pass clears the buffer(s) on load is part of the render pass's setup. There is the `loadOp` field in every attachment which states how it should use any previous data in the attachment (if any).

In your case, because you're constantly accumulating distinct rendering processes into the same images, you want the `loadOp` to load the data, not clear it. You can explicitly clear the attachments the first time you execute the render pass with `vkCmdClearAttachments`.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to use `vkCmdClearAttachment` in a render pass and it worked. But when I tried splitting my render pass into two passes, in which I cleared in the first pass, and draw triangles in the second pass, I get a gray image, indicating that the start of the second pass initated my depth buffer to an unknown value even though I set `loadOp` to `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE`. I get the same result if i use `loadOp=VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD`. Any idea?

Comment: The load op should be to load, not "don't care", because you *very much do care*. Also, do you have appropriate external dependencies established, as well as image layouts and such?

Comment: I changed `loadOp` to `VK_ATTACHEMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD`, changed the attachement descriptions `initialLayout` to be equal to the value of the `finalLayout` of the first pass. But, the attachements are still cleared by the second render pass. How would I set up the dependencies for the first and the second pass to do what I want?

Comment: @DovGrobgeld: I'm not able to debug code from a vague description of what *some* of your code is doing.

Comment: Sigh, I realize that using comments in StackOverflow is not the best place for this kind of discussion. I'm however not sure what would be a better forum to use. Any recommendations?